# Showing an openstreetmap using ExtJs 4.2.1 and GeoExt

Tags: extjs, openlayers, openstreetmap, geoext

well I am trying to apply the PgroutingWorkshop using PHP, ExtJS, GeoExt and OpenLayers.
I fact in the tutorial, they are using ExtJS 3.3.1 I think and me the 4.2.1
First of all, they mentionned a JS script called ext-base that doesn't exist on the 4.2.1 version. I said, this can not be very important, so I applied every thing they said but nothing appears.
I tried another tutorial from the official website of geoExt without osm map and it doen't work neither.
here is the code :

```
        <html>
<head>
<title>Une page GeoExt de base</title>
<script src="ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="ext/ext-all.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/resources/css/ext-all.css"></link>
<script src="OpenLayers/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="GeoExt/lib/GeoExt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="GeoExt/resources/css/geoext-all-debug.css"></link>

    <script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function() {
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map();
        var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "Global Imagery",
            "http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms",
            {layers: "bluemarble"}
        );
        map.addLayer(layer);

        new GeoExt.MapPanel({
            renderTo: 'usthb',
            height: 400,
            width: 600,
            map: map,
            title: 'A Simple GeoExt Map'
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="usthb" style="width:100% height=200% "></div>
    <div id="navigator"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: So what is your problem in one sentence?

Comment: Simply, nothing works, I tried all the tutorials,  from GeoExt and pgRoutingworkshop And nothing shows on the screen, I get a blank page, so the ExtHs and Geo Ext are not loading